# Convert Unix time stamp to readable format not working in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, datetime, unix-timestamp

I was trying to convert a timestamp to a format(July 14, 2016) and I used the following code:

```
    var wiDaterawa = entry.data.channel.created;
    var wiDateraw = new Date(entry.data.channel.created * 1000);    
    var months =  
    ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var year = wiDateraw.getFullYear();
    var month = months[wiDateraw.getMonth()];
    var date = wiDateraw.getDate();
    var wiDate = month + ' ' + date + ', '  + year ;
```

By this code I tried to pass the timestamp: 1481791797000 and got the result as:

> Feb 11, 48926

The year is not showing in proper manner.
When I tested it with:

```
var wiDate = new Date(entry.data.channel.created);
```

It showed :

> Thu Dec 15 2016 12:49:57 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time)

Also I tried it with php code:

```
 <?php print $returnValue = date('M d,Y', 1481791797000); ?>
```

Got the result:

> Feb 11, 48926

I need the JavaScript based result as I am binding all the result in the a JavaScript function.

Could you please help me to sort it out?

Comment: When you use the timestamp without multiplying it by a thousand (i.e. 1481791797) JavaScript will give you "Dec 15, 2016". Is that not what you wanted? If you want it to give you "July 14, 2016" for that timestamp you're out of luck no matter what language you use...

Comment: @moopet yes you are correct. It works now.thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a library like moment.js

http://momentjs.com/